# Charles Proxy Rewrite vs MapLocal

Tags: proxy, url-rewriting, mocking, charles-proxy

I've been working with Charles proxy these past few days to attempt to mock out a few responses specifically the rewrite tool.

I was surprised to find that the Rewrite tool can't rewrite the response with data it gleans from the request. As powerful as it is, and it really is powerful some of the shortcomings I've found or haven't figured out how to achieve with the rewrite tool are :-

- Doesn't intercept the call as such, it just rewrites the request/response on the way in and the way out.
- Can't use a regex match in the request as a group in the response.
- Can't also incorporate a mapLocal rule to read from a file so that the call isn't made and then amend the response with a further rewrite rule.
- MapLocal files can't include regex matches from the rewrite tool so the data always has to be static unless you amend the file in the background between calls.

I still believe Charles is one of the best tools I know, I'm just surprised that it can't do these things as they were the first thing I tried to do with it with regards mocking responses.

If anyone knows of anyway to pass data from the request to the response body using rewrite I'd be greatly appreciative.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: What I can only say is: let them know about your needs. Send them the link to this post, so they can see what would be great to have on their next release.

Comment: Good man Lluís! I did just that this morning :)

Comment: From what I know, it's impossible to achieve it in Charles because there is no way to extract the request and pass it to the response. If you insist do it, let try Scripting Tool (with Shared State) from Proxyman app https://github.com/ProxymanApp/Proxyman/issues/611

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use another tool like Scripting from Proxyman, which resolves all your problem with the current ReWrite tool

> Doesn't intercept the call as such, it just rewrites the request/response on the way in and the way out.

The [Scripting tool](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/script#4-examples) could intercept the Request or Response on the fly and let you modify the header, status code, body, ... with Javascript code.

You can also use [built-in addons](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/addons) or write an addon by your-self, such as Hashing, encrypting, zip/unzip, UUID Generator, ...

> Can't use a regex match in the request as a group in the response.

You can define a [Regex Match](https://docs.proxyman.io/basic-features/regex#regex) to match multiple requests in the single rule.

> Can't also incorporate a mapLocal rule to read from a file so that the call isn't made and then amend the response with a further rewrite rule.

You can import a [Local File in the script](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code#json) and update the Request/Response Body on the fly.

> MapLocal files can't include regex matches from the rewrite tool so the data always has to be static unless you amend the file in the background between calls.

You can use [if statement](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code#use-multiple-json-files) or [Regex in the Script](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code#regex) to select which Map Local file should be used.

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of this app, and hopefully it can help find the answer.